# Flutter FutureBuilder to states_rebuilder

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to convert a flutter app to use **states_rebuilder** but I'm running into a problem with futures.

This is the original code and it works fine:

```
      body: FutureBuilder(
    future: ScheduleScreenModel.getMedicationData(),
    builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
        return Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        );
      } else if (!snapshot.hasData) {
        return null;
      }
      List<Medication> medications = snapshot.data;
      return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: medications.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          final medication = medications[index];
```

This is my attempt at states_rebuilder:

```
body: Injector(
    inject: [
      Inject.future(() => ScheduleScreenModel().getMedicationData()),
    ],
    builder: (context) {
      final snapshot =
          Injector.getAsReactive<ScheduleScreenModel>(context: context)
              .snapshot;
      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
        return Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        );
      } else if (!snapshot.hasData) {
        return null;
      }
      List<Medication> medications = snapshot.data as List<Medication>;
      return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: medications.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          final medication = medications[index];
```

I've tried casting the result, with no luck, but I think I'm totally missing something. 
my latest issue is this:

```
Failed assertion: line 148 pos 12: 'T != dynamic': is not true.
```

The future being called in ScheduleScreenModel is simple.

```
class ScheduleScreenModel {
  getMedicationData() {
    final _uid = Injector.get<User>().uid;
    final result = DatabaseService.getMedicationData(_uid);
    return result;
  }
}
```

Any thoughts?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

OK,
this was solved by adding `<List<Medication>>` to getMedicationData and then changing the getAsReactive from `<ScheduleScreenModel>` to `<List<Medication>>`.

However, I'm thinking that the FutureBuilder option is a little more elegant for this use case unless there's a better way of doing this.